# Delphi XE10 Seattle JVCL failing install

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, jedi, jvcl

I am unable to use the GetIt or the Manual approach to install the JVCL into Delphi XE10 Seattle.
I always receive the error during package compilation that the unit 'jvInterpreter_DBTables" is not found.  I see the pas file in the directory listed with the error c:....\Studio\17.0\CatalogRepository\JediVisualComponentLibraryJVCL-3.49\run\

I do have Delphi 2010 and Delphi XE8 installed as well. 
The JCL installed just fine and Seattle loads with the package version 2.80.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: You have old copies of some JCL and JVCL units (DCU), or DCPs or BPLs in your library path or conflicting old JVCL or JCL BPLs your windows system `PATH`?  Start up Delphi with a fresh registry: `bds.exe -RSEEMS_FRESH_TO_ME` and try it from there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried uninstalling and then running xe10 with the -RSEEMS_FRESH_TO_ME and it produced the same result.  I have verified in my PATH that there is no other JVCL units.  I have tried uninstalling JVCL from Delphi 2010 & XE8 and XE10

Comment: Unselect the package that contains JvInterpreter and try to continue.  I seriously doubt you actually effectively searched your system for files that are in your way.  Not just the windows path but every folder in your current Delphi 10 Seattle LIBRARY PATH in the Tools Options dialog.

Comment: Thank you again Warren.  I am doing an system wide search for jvCore*.bpl in hopes of finding some stray files.  I have gone through each folder in my library path and nothing points to any JVCL files.

Comment: If you don't find any jv*.bpl files, start looking for any JVCL or JCL .pas or .dcu or .dcp or .bpl files, probably inside some other project, that are in your library path or windows path.

Comment: Thanks again Warren.  The only files I found were in the Studio\17.0\CustomerRepository and within a folder I had created to download the JVCL source after the GetIt package installations kept failing.  I was able to get it to install WITHOUT the PascalInterpreter.  I will keep digging.

Comment: Warren, why would the installer find the correct files for everything but the jvPascalInterpreter?

Comment: Maybe you should probably go clean out your default BPL and DCP folders: `C:\users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl` and the Dcp folder right beside it.  It's finding some crap somewhere and you need to find the crap (bps/dcps/dcus) and remove them.

Comment: Thanks again Warren,  I will give it a try.  I will uninstall all the JVCL and make sure no Jv*.* files exist in those folders.  I will post the results.

Answer (score 0):

i did it.
Process installation (on start) modifed file jvcld23.inc {$DEFINE USE_BDE}
you have open in notepad and modifed again {.$DEFINE USE_BDE}
and save.

its worked for me.)

Comment: modifed need on process started.!